# React/redux same actions for different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I got react/redux simple blog project. Users can add/delete/edit articles and like/unlike it. I made "like" at articles list, but Im stuck when tryed to make like/dislike for single article page. I got actions ARTICLE_LIKE and ARTICLE_UNLIKE - and it just should post the same thing (/articles/${slug}/favorite) no matter is it list of articles or single article page. I got reducer for articles list

```
return {
                ...state,
                articles: state.articles.map(article => {
                        if (article.slug === action.payload.article.slug) {
                            return {
                                ...article,
                                favorited: action.payload.article.favorited,
                                favoritesCount: action.payload.article.favoritesCount
                            };
                        }
                        return article;
                })
            };
```

When it articleslist i got "articles" in state when it single page, I got "article".

And I can do it for single article page. but not for both in the same reducer. Should I need to made one more action? Or is it the way to do it for single article page and for articles list. I need little help, or advice how to do that. don't want to do two same actions code for different pages :/

full code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-mcnulty-x231v)

Comment: How can I go to single article page?

Comment: I made it possible for one-page articles to be viewed by non-login users. But in any case likes are tied to users, so if I make it possible to put likes to non-login users, there will be an error. :(  But its not my API for testing and everyone can signup with any email and password.